# M_PI in VS2010: working in Debug conf but not in Release

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmath

In my unmanaged C++ source i have:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
```

and then I use M_PI a couple of times.
Compiling in Debug configuration works flawlessly but in Release it gives:

> error C2065: 'M_PI' : undeclared identifier

What could be the configuration property causing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved.

I had put

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
```

before

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

With Precompiled Headers on (/Yu), as it's in Release mode, everything above it is ignored.

Answer (score 3):

The following code compiles just fine in both debug and release for me:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>

int main(void)
{
    double x = M_PI;
    return 0;
}
```

Your issue may lay elsewhere in your code. Do you have conditional compilation anywhere for debug or release modes?

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for differences in the configurations Debug and release:

Most important:

- include Files
- defines

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with precompiled header.
In Release mode, make sure the pch.cpp precompiled header is created (/Yc).